# Using Flow widget instead of BottomNavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use Flow widget instead of BottomNavigationBar.

this is my code.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final delegate = S.of(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: DrawerWidget(),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
          _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
          Positioned(
            child: Container(
              child: Flow(
                delegate: FlowMenuDelegate(menuAnimation: menuAnimation),
                children: menuItems
                    .map<Widget>((IconData icon) => flowMenuItem(icon))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
  }
```

[image]

But after adding left, right, bottom, or top properties to the Positioned widget, the Flow widget gon.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ConstrainedBox` and set `Stack fit` and `Positioned` with `Container`

```
SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                ...
                Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: 65,
                        child: FlowMenu()))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: FlowTest(),
    );
  }
}

class FlowTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlowTestState createState() => _FlowTestState();
}

class _FlowTestState extends State<FlowTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 5,
                          physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return  Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  child:  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(Icons.format_list_numbered,
                                          color: Colors.white),
                                      Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0)),
                                      Text(index.toString(),
                                          style:  TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: GridView.count(
                                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
                                    childAspectRatio: 1.2,
                                    children: List.generate(
                                      8,
                                          (index) {
                                        return Container(
                                          child: Card(
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: 65,
                        child: FlowMenu()))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlowMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlowMenuState createState() => _FlowMenuState();
}

class _FlowMenuState extends State<FlowMenu>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController menuAnimation;
  IconData lastTapped = Icons.notifications;
  final List<IconData> menuItems = <IconData>[
    Icons.home,
    Icons.new_releases,
    Icons.notifications,
    Icons.settings,
    Icons.menu,
  ];

  void _updateMenu(IconData icon) {
    if (icon != Icons.menu) setState(() => lastTapped = icon);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    menuAnimation = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  Widget flowMenuItem(IconData icon) {
    final double buttonDiameter =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / menuItems.length;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        fillColor: lastTapped == icon ? Colors.amber[700] : Colors.blue,
        splashColor: Colors.amber[100],
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(buttonDiameter, buttonDiameter)),
        onPressed: () {
          _updateMenu(icon);
          menuAnimation.status == AnimationStatus.completed
              ? menuAnimation.reverse()
              : menuAnimation.forward();
        },
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 45.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Flow(
        delegate: FlowMenuDelegate(menuAnimation: menuAnimation),
        children: menuItems
            .map<Widget>((IconData icon) => flowMenuItem(icon))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlowMenuDelegate extends FlowDelegate {
  FlowMenuDelegate({this.menuAnimation}) : super(repaint: menuAnimation);

  final Animation<double> menuAnimation;

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FlowMenuDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return menuAnimation != oldDelegate.menuAnimation;
  }

  @override
  void paintChildren(FlowPaintingContext context) {
    double dx = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < context.childCount; ++i) {
      dx = context.getChildSize(i).width * i;
      context.paintChild(
        i,
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
          dx * menuAnimation.value,
          0,
          0,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain actually what happened?

Comment: How to make it scrollable.

Comment: alignment problem cause Flow component disappear. sorry I do not know how to make it scroll. this is the first time I use Flow compoent.